# Screen shows only horizontal stripes after login

Tags: 13.04, screen

After upgrading to 13.04 only horizontal stripes are displayed after logging in. It needs several restarts to get a proper display on the screen.

Comment: Could you add *any* detail about the hardware?

Answer (score 0):

open terminal and type following code:

`unity --reset`

and then reboot system.